# Wordpress custom field order by

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to order by the custom field `InPrice` but not able to do that. I'd know if possible in another way makes it `('orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC',)`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'meta_key' => 'InPrice',
    'meta_value'   =>  array( $pieces[0], $pieces[1]),
    'meta_type'    => 'numeric',
    'meta_compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'   => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'btown' => array(    
                    'key'     => 'Town', 
                    'value'   => $town,
                    'type'     => 'STRING',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                ),
                broom' => array(
                    'key'     => 'Rooms', 
                    'value'   => $rooms,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                ),                                                                      
            ), 
       ),               
);
```

Comment: what did you get in result? 
can i have example data?

Comment: example of sql request obtained after execution?

Comment: example of result and a screen of your db table if is possible

Comment: I obtain the results but the are not ordered by the custom field InPrice. 
The query generated is: 
Last SQL-Query: SELECT wpbk_posts.* FROM wpbk_posts INNER JOIN wpbk_postmeta ON ( wpbk_posts.ID = wpbk_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wpbk_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wpbk_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) INNER JOIN wpbk_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wpbk_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wpbk_postmeta.meta_key = 'InPrice' AND CAST(wpbk_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '150000' AND '200000' ) AND ( ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'Town' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE

Comment: The code is too big.. I can't post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

referred to [Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) 
 you can use something like code below :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'age',
            'value'   => array( array( $pieces[0], $pieces[1]) ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ), // other meta queries that you want 
    //don't forget to set a relation type for them in here ex:'relation'=>'AND',
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: thank you, I solved. I made confusion between meta_key and meta_query